# CallBack iOS not working

Tags: objective-c, codenameone

I'm trying to call a static method of a codename one class from a native interface implementation in Objective-C (iOS). I thus use a callback. I imported the header file of the wanted class and the

`#include "CodenameOne_GLViewController.h"`

The building works but the callback does not work (the method takes a string and shows a dialog with the given string but nothing is displayed when running the app). Here is the callback line:

`package_ClassName_methodName___java_lang_String(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG fromNSString(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG myString));`

Where my string is declared as `NSString * mySTring = @"hi!"`.

I tried a simple callback method that does not take arguments. Unfortunately, it did not work either.

`package_ClassName_methodName__(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG);`

Did I miss something?

Comment: Post your code snippet

Comment: Your declaration is mySTring, but your passing myString. The T case difference is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the optimizer stripped away the native callback code because it couldn't detect usage so the callback is happening but the method is blank.

You need to trick the optimizer so it won't strip these callback methods in your main class add the filed:

```
boolean fake;
```

Notice I don't initialize it and don't declare visibility, both are important!

If it's private javac might detect this and optimize it away.

Then in your init code do this:

```
// this is always false and is here to prevent the optimizer from stripping code used from native code
if(fake) {
   MyCallbackClass.callback();
}
```

You can pass anything to the callback since the call will never happen but you need to "invoke" all the callback methods to trick the optimizer.